# Show number of close votes cast in the profile summary

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the summary tab, currently only the following vote stats are shown:

- up votes
- down votes
- question
- answer

Would it be a good idea to add close votes to that list as a private statistic, for users who can close-vote?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to see this information?  Why would the site be better if this were shown?

Comment: I don't know about others but it's useful for me to see how many close votes I've cast alongside the others, as I feel like there's something missing there

Comment: I asked you why you think it would be useful.  Saying *that* it would be useful isn't explaining *why* it would be useful.

Comment: @Servy It's useful in the same way seeing up and down votes are useful, just a summary statistic to see what I'm doing on the site.

Comment: So you're saying that you can't come up with a single reason for why it would be useful when asked?  You have once again asserted *that* you think it would be useful without explaining *why* it is useful.  What are you going to do with the information, how will it help you?  Come up with an example of what you would do differently with this information.

Comment: Right now I feel like that number could be held against a user, especially by newcomers who have a grudge against you, or some future employers who believe that they can derive some kind of behavioral analysis out of that information. I'd rather have them know less about me.

Comment: @NobuGames Couldn't you say the same for up & down votes? I think the solution to that is by hiding them in certain cases.

Comment: @Servy I've already explained that, it will help me get an overall picture of my voting patterns on the site.

Comment: "getting the successful close votes for a particular user is rather trivial" ([quote source with SEDE query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160981/show-successful-close-reopen-votes-in-sede-regardless-of-if-theyve-expired-or-n#comment467269_160981)) -- this is skewed though, because [close votes cast on deleted posts are not included in Data.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se)

Comment: @simonzack And *what are you going to do with that information*?  Understanding your voting patterns is a means to an end, not an en in and of itself.  Once you understand how you have been voting, what will you do with that understanding, how will it affect you and other people?  So far you have been unable to describe a single meaningful effect that it would have.  One other person has come up with one negative effect.

Comment: @gnat That qualification makes the state almost useless.  Virtually no meaningful information can be gleaned from it.

Comment: I agree in case of the downvotes, that's true. Upvotes just indicate some kind of "positive engangement" with this platform. Downvotes could be interpreted by some people who feel intimidated by Stackexchange mechanics as: "how much of a dick are you". So, that's just me and my opinion and I do not suggest any kind of fix here: I decided to down-vote way less, since I figured out, that the numbers are on my public profile page. I think twice about casting down-votes.

Comment: @Servy How about this, how many questions I think are closeworthy, compared to the number of questions I think are good (my upvotes), to be a personal metric on whether people have been asking good questions in the areas I frequent. Another one I can think of, to know that I've been helping the site close off bad questions, in the same way that I know I've been helping people when my rep increases.

Comment: @simonzack Okay.  Now were getting *somewhere*.  What are you going to do with *that* information?  How is it helpful to you to have this metric of "how good the questions are in the areas you frequent"?  Will it affect which areas you frequent, help you decide how you search for questions, in what way will your life be better with this knowledge?

Comment: @Servy It makes me feel better when I know I'm helping the site close off bad questions. It also helps me decide whether to look at better quality questions in general before deciding to answer, if it ends up that I'm closing many questions.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're requesting these numbers to be visible for all users, or only for yourself? Because you can already see how many close votes you cast. Click the "votes" tab in your profile, click the "closure" button below it, and you see the number at the top of the list.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Only for myself, I've clarified this in the question. I know I can see it there, but I feel putting it next to up and down makes thing easier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I believe most of the concerns people voiced were about other people being able to see the statistics.